# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{H_n}{p_n}-\frac{n}{n^n})$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers, harmonic-numbers

Does this diverge or converge ?? $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{H_n}{p_n}-\frac{n}{n^n})$$
where $H_n$ is the nth harmonic number, $p_n$ is the nth prime.

My impression is that it diverges, but I don't see how I can prove it!
I tried on wolframalpha but no clue.

Comment: I believe that $\sum\dfrac{H_n}{p_n}$ diverges since the sequence of partial sums is increasing.

Comment: That would mean that $H_n$ increases faster than $p_n $ interesting result!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A classic result is
$$H_n\sim_\infty \ln n$$
and by the [Flegner's result](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nombre_premier)$^{(1)}$ in $1990$ we have
$$ 0.91\; n \ln(n) < p_n < 1.7\; n \ln(n)$$
hence the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{p_n}$$
is divergent. Since the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^n}$$
is obviously convergent then given series is divergent.

$(1)$ The page is in French language.

Comment: [$\mathbf{+1}$](http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/250x250/43299988.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{n}{n^n}<\infty$ but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{p_n}=\infty$.